# ruby on rails gallery ArgumentError Unknown key(s): attributes, discard_if attachment_fu and paperclip

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, attachment-fu

Hi I'm trying to build a little gallery for myself and tried this link for multiple uploads for a album: http://www.mfischer.com/wordpress/2009/02/02/multiple-image-upload-and-crop-with-rails/

So far I'm running into following error when I visit *localhost:3000/albums/new* :

```
ArgumentError in AlbumsController#index
Unknown key(s): attributes, discard_if
```

Since I am not sure whether the attachment_fu-Plugin nor the paperclip-gem (which I use) are used correctly, maybe thats a problem to look at too?

Further my versions:

```
Ruby version    1.9.2 (x86_64-linux)
RubyGems version    1.7.1
Rack version    1.2
Rails version   3.0.4
Active Record version   3.0.4
Action Pack version 3.0.4
Active Resource version 3.0.4
Action Mailer version   3.0.4
Active Support version  3.0.4
```

Can't tell the exact attachment_fu version... :/
Paperclip version is this:

```
paperclip (2.3.8)

My album model is this:
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110404082122
#
# Table name: albums
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  location   :string(255)
#  date       :date
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :images,
        :attributes => true,
        :discard_if => proc { |upload| upload.photo_file_size.nil? }
end
```

and my image model is like this:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110404082122
#
# Table name: images
#
#  id          :integer         not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  date        :date
#  landscape   :boolean
#  flash       :boolean
#  cameramaker :string(255)
#  cameramodel :string(255)
#  lens        :string(255)
#  flength     :string(255)
#  aperture    :string(255)
#  exposure    :string(255)
#  iso         :string(255)
#  album_id    :integer
#  filesize    :integer
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
#

require 'RMagick'

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  has_attached_file :photo,
            :styles => {
              :thumb => ["150x150", :jpg],
              :pagesize => ["500x400", :jpg],
            },
            :default_style => :pagesize
end
```

Do you need anything more?
I don't understand what the problem is.. I think the attachment_fu plugin is too old or I missed something to say rails to use it...?

Thanks for your time!

Wanye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

There is no any `:attributes` or `:discard_if` options for `has_many` association

Looks like in that tutorial author used `attribute_fu` plugin. So you need to install it

https://github.com/jamesgolick/attribute_fu

Comment: So I should use has_attachment instead? Because at [link]http://www.mfischer.com/wordpress/2009/02/02/multiple-image-upload-and-crop-with-rails/ he uses has_many with those attributes...

Comment: I did, which seems not very operatable... Since this is the Output: `[me@pc gallery]$ rails plugin install http://github.com/woahdae/attachment_fu.git -r rails3
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/wayne/DEV/ror/gallery/vendor/plugins/attachment_fu/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 71, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (67/67), done.
remote: Total 71 (delta 11), reused 25 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (71/71), done.
From http://github.com/woahdae/attachment_fu
 * branch            rails3     -> FETCH_HEAD` And more output ommitted which says how to work with the plugin.

Comment: I've never used this plugin. Did you restarted your app?

Comment: Yes, restarted rails server more than once. Maybe it's not working correctly with rails 3.0.4 :/

Comment: check out documentation of the plugin. I don't like to use them

Comment: `gallery/vendor/plugins/attachment_fu/app/views` is in the show env dump... Maybe I find something about this plugin installation (which I didn't as I searched last three times -.-). I like gems much more :<

Comment: try `rails plugin install git://github.com/giraffesoft/attribute_fu.git`

Comment: Yes, tried that too, but I get: `fatal: remote error: 
  Could not find Repository giraffesoft/attribute_fu` because they moved it to [github.com/jamesgolick] but there is no attribute_fu anymore /o\

Comment: Oh noez :O They moved it away, but yeah attribute_fu is what I needed... Blindingly searched for attachment_fu :( Sorry! Thanks so much!

Comment: [http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html] So this is what I need if I want up-to-date code :)